# Weak topology on Baire measures "obviously" Hausdorff

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

In the book "*Weak Convergence of Measure*" by Bogachev the
*Baire $\sigma$-algebra* $\mathcal{B}a(X)$ of a (Hausdorff) topological space $X$ is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
containing all functionally open sets, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
with respect to which all continuous functions are measurable (see
Definition 4.1.3 in the book). A countably additive measure on $\mathcal{B}a(X)$
is called a *Baire measure* on $X$. We write $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$
for the set of all finite Baire measures on $X$.

Denote by $C_{b}(X)$ the space of all bounded continuous functions
on $X$. The set $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$ can be equipped with the
*weak topology*, which is defined by the requirement that a net
$\{\mu_{\alpha}\}\subseteq\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$ weakly converges
to $\mu\in\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$ if and only if for every $f\in C_{b}(X)$
the equality
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\alpha}\int_{X}f(x)d\mu_{\alpha}(x)=\int_{X}f(x)d\mu(x)
\end{eqnarray}
holds (see Definition 4.2.1 in the book).

**Question:** In the book it is mentioned that the weak topology
on $\mathcal{M}_{\sigma}(X)$ is "obviously" always Hausdorff.
But it is not clear to me why this should be the case.

To make this more precise, what is confusing to me is that the definition
of the Baire $\sigma$-algebra uses general continuous functions,
whereas the weak topology uses bounded continuous functions. I am wondering how these two ingredients fit together.

Comment: Is there some finiteness assumptions on the Baire measures you are considering? Otherwise the integrals may not make sense. For example the counting measure on $X = [0, 1]$, restricted to Baire sets, is a Baire measure in your terminology, but $f \in C_b(X)$ is never integrable unless $f = 0$.

Comment: @DavidGao, it is not very explicit in the book, but I think that the author indeed only considers the space of finite Baire measures equipped with this topology.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topological space is Hausdorff iff limits of nets are unique. Thus, it suffices to show that, if $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are finite Baire measures s.t. $\int f d\mu_1 = \int f d\mu_2$ for all $f \in C_b(X)$, then $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

To do this, recall that Baire-measurable functions are the smallest collection of functions that contains all continuous functions and is closed under taking pointwise limits of sequences of functions. We claim that it is possible to restrict the range to $[0, 1]$. Indeed, if $f$ is a real-valued function, then $\max\{0, \min\{f, 1\}\}$ is a real-valued function taking values in $[0, 1]$. If $f$ already takes values in $[0, 1]$, then $\max\{0, \min\{f, 1\}\} = f$. If $f$ is continuous or Baire-measurable, then so is $\max\{0, \min\{f, 1\}\}$. If $f_i$ is a sequence converging pointwise to $f$, then $\max\{0, \min\{f_i, 1\}\}$ converges pointwise to $\max\{0, \min\{f, 1\}\}$. Thus, Baire-measurable functions taking values in $[0, 1]$ are the smallest collection of functions that contains all continuous functions taking values in $[0, 1]$ and is closed under taking pointwise limits of sequences of functions.

Continuous functions taking values in $[0, 1]$ are in particular bounded, so $\int f d\mu_1 = \int f d\mu_2$ for all continuous functions taking values in $[0, 1]$. If $f_i$ is a sequence of Baire-measurable functions taking values in $[0, 1]$ that converges pointwise to $f$, then $f$ is Baire-measurable, takes values in $[0, 1]$, and, by Dominated Convergence, $\int f_i d\mu_j \rightarrow \int f d\mu_j$ for $j = 1, 2$. Thus, if $\int f_i d\mu_1 = \int f_i d\mu_2$ for all $i$, then $\int f d\mu_1 = \int f d\mu_2$. Hence, the collection of functions $f$ taking values in $[0, 1]$ for which $\int f d\mu_1 = \int f d\mu_2$ contains continuous functions taking values in $[0, 1]$ and is closed under taking pointwise limits of sequences. Whence, this holds for all Baire-measurable functions taking values in $[0, 1]$. In particular, this holds for indicator functions of Baire sets, so $\mu_1(A) = \mu_2(A)$ for all Baire $A$, i.e., $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot! I have one more question: to me it looks like the assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff is not needed in your proof. Does this mean that the statement holds for general topological spaces?

Comment: @Botwinnik As far as I can tell, you don’t need $X$ to be Hausdorff, yes. Though without some kind of separation assumptions, you wouldn’t have many continuous functions on $X$ and so you wouldn’t have many Baire sets and the statement is somewhat boring. For example, the only real-valued continuous functions on an infinite set equipped with the cofinite topology are constant ones, so the only Baire sets are the empty set and the entire space. (Admittedly the same can happen to Hausdorff spaces, so I would have assumed some stronger separation assumptions.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!